# In python, how can you compare two CalVer strings to determine if one is greater than, lesser than, or equal to, the other?

Tags: python, versioning

I have the occasional need to adjust my python scripts based on the versions of various dependencies. Most often in my case, a python codebase works alongside front-end javascript that may be running releases spanning multiple years. If a javascript dependency has a version greater than A, the python should do B. If the dependency has a version less than X, the python should do Y, etc.

These dependencies are [calendar versioned](https://calver.org/calendar_versioning.html) (CalVer). While I've located many tools for maintaining a project's own CalVer, I was unable to find a ready-made solution to evaluate CalVers in this fashion.

```
if "YY.MM.DD" > "YY.MM.DD.MICRO":
    # Do this thing
else:
    # Do that thing
```

Comparing dates is easy enough, but when `MICRO` versions come into the mix, things get more complex.

Answer (score 2):

The Python Packaging Authority ([PyPA](https://www.pypa.io)) maintains the [`packaging`](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) library, which, among other things, implements version handling according to [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) ("Version Identification and Dependency Specification"), including Calendar Versioning.

Examples (taken from Dennis's answer):

```py
>>> from packaging import version
>>> version.parse('2021.01.31') >= version.parse('2021.01.30.dev1')
True
>>> version.parse('2021.01.31.0012') >= version.parse('2021.01.31.1012')
False
```

Comment: That appears to be the package I was seeking, before deciding to write this function. I'll leave my answer here for those who prefer not to add, or are unable to add, a dependency to their project.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own solution to allow me to compare CalVer strings like below.

```
subject = "2021.01.31"
test = "2021.01.30.dev1"

if calver_evaluate(operator="gte", subject=subject, test=test):
   # if "2021.01.31" >= "2021.01.30.dev1"
   result = True

subject = "2021.01.31.0012"
test = "2021.01.31.1012"

if calver_evaluate(operator="gte", subject=subject, test=test):
   # if "2021.01.31.0012" >= "2021.01.30.1012"
   result = False
```

Full details on the operations are included the function's docstring. Note some of the limited rules around evaluating micros that cannot be converted to integers.

```
import datetime

def calver_evaluate(operator=None, subject=None, test=None):
    """Evaluates two calver strings based on the operator.

    Params
    ------
    operator : str
        Defines how to evaluate the subject and test params. Acceptable values are:
        - "gt" or ">" for greater than
        - "gte" or ">=" for greater than or equal to
        - "e", "eq", "equal", "=", or "==" for equal to
        - "lt" or "<" for less than
        - "lte" or "<=" for less than or equal to
    subject : str
        A calver string formatted as YYYY.0M.0D.MICRO (recommended) or YY.MM.DD.MICRO.
        https://calver.org/calendar_versioning.html
    test : str
        A calver string to evaluate against the subject, formatted as YYYY.0M.0D.MICRO 
        (recommended) or YY.MM.DD.MICRO.
        https://calver.org/calendar_versioning.html

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        The results of the `subject`:`test` evaluation using the `operator`.

    Notes
    -----
    The MICRO segment of the calver strings are only considered in the following
    scenarios.
        1. One calver has a MICRO value and the other does not. The calver without a 
        MICRO value is evaluated as `0`, making the calver *with* the MICRO, no matter
        what the value, as the greater of the two.
        `2021.01.01 == 2021.01.01.0`, therefore `2021.01.01.2 > 2021.01.01` and
        `2021.01.01.dev1 > 2021.01.01`
        2. Both calvers have MICRO values that are numeric and able to be converted to
        integers.
        3. Both calvers have string MICRO values **and** the operator selected is 
        "equals".

    """
    if not operator or not subject or not test:
        raise Exception("calver_evaluate: Missing keyword argument.")

    allowed = ["lt","<","lte","<=","e","eq","equal","=","==","gte",">=","gt",">"]
    if operator not in allowed:
        raise Exception("calver_evaluate: Unrecognized evaluation operator.")

    sparts = subject.split(".")
    syear = int(sparts[0]) if int(sparts[0]) > 100 else int(sparts[0]) + 2000
    smonth = int(sparts[1])
    sday = int(sparts[2])
    sdate = datetime.date(syear, smonth, sday)
    smicro = sparts[3] if len(sparts) > 3 else 0

    tparts = test.split(".")
    tyear = int(tparts[0]) if int(tparts[0]) > 100 else int(tparts[0]) + 2000
    tmonth = int(tparts[1])
    tday = int(tparts[2])
    tdate = datetime.date(tyear, tmonth, tday)
    tmicro = tparts[3] if len(tparts) > 3 else 0

    if unicode(smicro).isnumeric() and unicode(tmicro).isnumeric():
        smicro = int(smicro)
        tmicro = int(tmicro)
    elif smicro == 0:
        tmicro = 1
    elif tmicro == 0:
        smicro = 1

    lt = ["lt","<"]
    lte = ["lte","<="]
    equal = ["e","eq","equal","=","=="]
    gte = ["gte",">="]
    gt = ["gt",">"]

    check_micro = (
        (
            isinstance(smicro, int) and isinstance(tmicro, int) and
            (smicro > 0 or tmicro > 0)
        ) or
        (
            operator in equal and 
            not isinstance(smicro, int) and 
            not isinstance(tmicro, int)
        )
    )

    def evaluate_micro(operator, smicro, tmicro):
        if operator in lt:
            if smicro < tmicro:
                return True
        elif operator in lte:
            if smicro <= tmicro:
                return True
        elif operator in equal:
            if smicro == tmicro:
                return True
        elif operator in gte:
            if smicro >= tmicro:
                return True
        elif operator in gt:
            if smicro > tmicro:
                return True

        return False

    if operator in lt and sdate <= tdate:
        if sdate < tdate:
            return True
        elif sdate == tdate and check_micro:
            return evaluate_micro(operator, smicro, tmicro) 

    elif operator in lte and sdate <= tdate:
        if sdate == tdate and check_micro:
            return evaluate_micro(operator, smicro, tmicro) 
        return True

    elif operator in equal:
        if sdate == tdate:
            if check_micro:
                return evaluate_micro(operator, smicro, tmicro) 
            return True

    elif operator in gte and sdate >= tdate:
        if sdate == tdate and check_micro:
            return evaluate_micro(operator, smicro, tmicro) 
        return True

    elif operator in gt and sdate >= tdate:
        if sdate > tdate:
            return True
        elif sdate == tdate and check_micro:
            return evaluate_micro(operator, smicro, tmicro) 

    return False
```

Comment: Maybe add `==` as one of the equality operators for consistency? Possibly even `eq` because the equality operator in python is overridden by redefining the `__eq__()` function?

Comment: Also, since you already have the year, month, and date, you can construct the `datetime` object using the constructor instead of `strptime`.